# No response from 2 working spi devices when they are stacked

Tags: circuit-design, spi

I have two identical SPI devices but each off them is on a separate board, they are connected via a header that allows the board to be "stacked" on top of the master controller. the signal will pass through two ICs before it reaches the slave device, a signal mux  [SN74CBTLV3257](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74cbtlv3257.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1617193506968) and a digital isolator [ISO7741](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso7741.pdf?ts=1617193849014&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). Here is the schematic.

[image]

I have already confirmed that each of the circuit works perfectly fine when it is alone. The problem lies when both of them are stacked, i can confirm that each slave device has received my spi transaction as i can visually see that it is doing what im telling it to. Supposedly the slave will send a response back but i am not getting any.

With a bit of tinkering around the circuit i have concluded that the signal from the slave device is not making it back to the controller. In the schematic above i tried probing testpoint A and testpoint B with my logic analyzer and this is what i got.

[image]

at point B the correct signal is still there ( i checked that it is indeed the correct response to what i sent), at point A the signal seems very noisy, an lastly at MISO (directly on the master controller pin) it doesnt see anything.

The only explination i can think of is something between the two ICs are interfering with each other preventing the signal to be pulled high/low. But i could not make out why it is interfering with each other. The mux is able to handle bi directional signal so it should be it, It might be the isolator, when the other isolator pulls low the two muxes somewhat forms a voltage divider with isolator 1 Dout outputing 3.3v and isolator 2 Dout trying to pull it to 0v, and assuming both muxes has same resistance the controller would essentially be seeing 1/2 of 3.3v. I have no idea if that sounds correct though but it would be hard to test without an oscilloscope.

Can anybody help me with what might be happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: Well, if there is a noisy problem, my favorite troubleshooting trick is (1) Lower SPI frequency to 100kHz, or even 10kHz, (2) Shorten wiring to less than 30cm if possbile. Also I don't understand why both CS1 and CS2 go to the same 3B1. Shouldn't they go different paths?

Comment: Both chips are missing important connections, like power supplies and grounds. If that is not the actual schematic, post the actual schematic. Most likely the isolator or mux is connected wrong and we need to see that. They might just both drive MISO pins.

Comment: @tlfong01 I tried lowering it to 1MHz and 100kHz and sadly the same behavior.  Since this is a stacking board there are actually no wires, each board is connected via a header that has female on the bottom and male on the top. The longest trace including the headers would be about 5cm. With that i think its not a noise problem, and it might be something wrong with the circuit. The top and bottom are on a different pcb, i have updated the schematic to make it a bit more clearer

Comment: @Justme I apologize for being lazy, i have updated the schematics to contain a bit more. I would argue that the connections are wrong since if i connect the controller to a single board only (board 1/board2) they would function normally and i am able to communicate with them no problem. the problem only start when i connect the controller to both of the boards, i can still send signal to either/both slave devices but i cant get a response back.

Comment: Yes, that proves that they work alone but both always drive the data to MCU so it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both muxes and isolators are always enabled. So the isolator data out to MCU MISO are both enabled and driving the same node. Neither the mux or the isolator are controlled to avoid this.

Comment: This is rather tricky to solve, controlling the mux is a no no since i cant control it individually. Connecting the CS to the enable of the isolator would have been a great idea but sadly the slave device is an active low, and the isolator is an active high. I have to order a single inverter IC. Do you have any ideas for a quick temporary fix?

Comment: Connect the unused CS that stays high to keep isolator enabled, so the CS that goes active low will disable the other isolator? It's a hack as it will still keep both isolators enabled while both chipselects are high.

Comment: That is a clever idea!  i was digging through my bins in hopes that i could find my nmos to create a deadbug logic inverter, but your idea much more simpler just needs a wire. If it works it will definitely buy me enough time for the new pcb boards to arrive. Would you agree that usig a logic inverter would be the proper permanent solution? i do intend to stack more than just 2

Comment: The inverter sounds like a solution. I do have to wonder  what is the point of the multiplexers then, and stacking a lot of these means you need a lot of chip selects and there will be a huge network of wiring driven by chips so there will be a lot of stray capacitance and stubs for the signals to reflect and bounce around. It might limit the SPI clock speed.

Comment: So i tried your solution and can confirm that am able to get a response from both devices now ! Thank you so much sir